# Add output to interactive Python console blocks in Sphinx docs?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

How can I add the output to interactive Python console blocks in Sphinx docs?

For example, so I can do something like:

```
First set the variable::

    >>> x = 1

Then print the variable::

    >>> print x
```

And have Sphinx automatically insert the output of `print x` into the documentation?

I've tried:

- `sphinxcontrib-autorun` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-autorun/0.1-20140415 — but it runs each block in a separate interpriter
- `IPython.sphinxext.ipython_directive` — but it forces IPython syntax instead of the "traditional" Python console.

Is there anything else that can do this?

Comment: I haven't seen any, but it's pretty easy to write a Directive subclass to do pretty much anything you can think of...

Comment: Could you give an example of how to do that?

Comment: Ah, I guess I can just copy the autorun directive.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I've gone ahead and built one of those here: https://bitbucket.org/wolever/sphinx-contrib/src/tip/autorun2/?at=default

Answer (score 2):

The docs for writing an extension for Sphinx is at http://sphinx-doc.org/extdev/index.html#dev-extensions

The only hint I would give is that using `self.state.nested_parse(..)` will save you a lot of headaches.  Here is the simplest extension I have:

```
class SvnRevisionDirective(Directive):
    """Directive to display subversion revision of the path.
    """
    has_content = True
    required_arguments = 1
    optional_arguments = 1
    final_argument_whitespace = False
    option_spec = {}

    def run(self):
        path = self.arguments[0]
        rev = svntools.Revision(path)   # uses subprocess etc.
        paragraph = nodes.paragraph()
        self.state.nested_parse(
            StringList([
                '**Revision:** r%d' % rev   # you can use regular rst syntax here(!)
            ]), 0, paragraph)
        return [paragraph]

...

def setup(app):
    ...
    app.add_directive('svnrevision', SvnRevisionDirective)
```

it's used like

```
.. snvrevision: 'my/file.py'
```